# How to recover deleted files from Trash on NAS?

Tags: delete, restore, trash

I have inadvertently deleted a large number of files from a directory on a file server (Synology DiskStation NAS).  I deleted them using Double Commander on a client PC running Ubuntu Studio 18.04. If I log into the NAS web interface (DSM), I can see what appear to be the deleted files in a subfolder named "files" of a parent folder named ".Trash-1993401104". The filenames agree with the ones I deleted and the last accessed date appears to be the time I deleted them (today) in Synology's File Station.  I presume that the folder "info" under the same parent directory contains the needed information to restore them whence they came, since the filenames there also correspond to the deleted files, but with the file extension, "TRASHINFO".
Unfortunately, I do not see these files in "Trash", which Ubuntu Studio opens in Thunar. I am more familiar with Windows than with Ubuntu and stupidly expected to be able to sort the contents of Trash by date deleted, but that seems not to be possible. I also expected to see where the files had been deleted from, since that is also displayed in the Windows recycle bin.
The nearest useful information I see in Thunar is "Date Accessed", but Thunar shows no date accessed newer than "Yesterday".
How can I find and restore these files from the Ubuntu GUI or, failing that, from a Ubuntu terminal session?

Comment: If you open the Trashcan / Rubish bin on the same Ubuntu client, you should be able to rightclick each document and restore it from the drop-down menu..

Comment: First I have to find the files to right-click them ;-)  I couldn't find the deleted files from the Ubuntu client, only from the management interface of the NAS.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry can't comment so have to "answer"
You say you can log into the NAS and see the files.
If this is via Thunar you should just be able to copy the file folder and paste into the file structure where you want and rename folder or move the contents (drag and drop) from the folder to intended place.
This adds security that files aren't lost while moving them around (essentially copy "trash" and then re-instate to correct position
If login is a web interface you may have tools to do similar to move/copy/rename folder into a better location or even onto your local machine to sort out that may help.
It may be that this is a platform agnostic issue - managed by web-app Synology tools

Is this relevant? https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Backup/How_do_I_restore_files_deleted_from_Synology_NAS

Consider editing your question to reflect what you can see with thunar and/or what you mean by logging into the NAS . Is synology recycle enabled as per link above.

Hope this is a little help!

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The link you provide is not relevant because I am not using Synology DSM's built-in recycle bin.  If I were, I would have found the deleted files in a subdirectory of a folder named #recycle, as described in the linked article. The folder I found them in, ".Trash-nnn", clearly indicates a Unix-like trash folder, and resembles those that I see in Thunar on my client PC.  I cannot find the deleted files (or the above-mentioned directory) in Thunar, and that is what bothers me.  I can only see the deleted files in Synology's File Station in the DSM web interface.

Comment: Actually, the link you provided *is* relevant, because I wound up using Synology's File Station in the NAS web interface to move the files back to their original directory, so I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Foremost; It's available from apt in Ubuntu,

```
sudo apt install foremost
```

from foremost's --help output:

```
foremost -h
foremost version 1.5.7 by Jesse Kornblum, Kris Kendall, and Nick Mikus.
$ foremost [-v|-V|-h|-T|-Q|-q|-a|-w-d] [-t <type>] [-s <blocks>] [-k <size>] 
    [-b <size>] [-c <file>] [-o <dir>] [-i <file] 

-V  - display copyright information and exit
-t  - specify file type.  (-t jpeg,pdf ...) 
-d  - turn on indirect block detection (for UNIX file-systems) 
-i  - specify input file (default is stdin) 
-a  - Write all headers, perform no error detection (corrupted files) 
-w  - Only write the audit file, do not write any detected files to the disk 
-o  - set output directory (defaults to output)
-c  - set configuration file to use (defaults to foremost.conf)
-q  - enables quick mode. Search are performed on 512 byte boundaries.
-Q  - enables quiet mode. Suppress output messages. 
-v  - verbose mode. Logs all messages to screen
```

> e.g: recover pdf and docx files from disk /dev/sda2:

EDIT:  Forgot to type the below. My bad.

```
foremost -i /dev/sda2 -t pdf docx
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am hoping to resolve this without installing additional software.

Comment: @RB Oh , my bad - Okay,  Sorry!    //Best wishes

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be dismissive.  I am very happy to have your suggestion in case I don't find a way to resolve this with standard tools.

Comment: @RB Ah No; Not what I meant :P  Thanks anyway;  I'm just careful when I'm writing, have a good day sir!  //Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using the Synology DSM File Station to move the files back to their original location. This is not an ideal answer, and was only practicable because all of the unintentionally deleted files came from the same directory. I experienced the following negative side effects:

1. I inadvertently restored some files which I had (intentionally) deleted from another directory a little earlier, and had to weed these out.
2. The file names of the restored files all had serial numbers appended to them.
3. After restoring the files by brute force, the .Trash folder is no doubt in an inconsistent condition.

I'm not sure, but after reading [this thread](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/thunar-unable-to-find-or-create-trash-directory-4175622983/), I suspect that my problem was an intrinsic limitation of Thunar.  If I had installed Dolphin (or maybe Nautilus), it would presumably have handled the deleted files as I expected.